# How can i change null value to "0" by CASE statement

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, etl

i got stuck to change a null value to "0" i write a code like this

```
SELECT 
  Custom.tblR_docProducer.libtxtDocumentID AS ParentID, 
  Custom.tblR_docProducer_grdProductRating.grdProductName AS ProductName, 
  Custom.tblR_docProducer_grdProductRating.grdProductType AS CategoryID,
  Custom.tblR_docProducer_grdProductRating.gdlkRating AS StarID, 
  Custom.tblR_docProducer_grdProductRating.gdlkRatingYear AS YearID, 
  1 AS DisplayOrder, 
  0 AS isDisabled
FROM Custom.tblR_docProducer 
INNER JOIN Custom.tblR_docProducer_grdProductRating 
  ON Custom.tblR_docProducer.Id = Custom.tblR_docProducer_grdProductRating._Parent
```

A result is still null like this

```
StarID
5
NULL
```

Comment: Not fully understanding your result but you could just wrap your column with the ISNULL() function. e.g. ISNULL(MyColumn, 0) as MyColumn

Comment: You never change the NULL to 0, and neither are there any case statements in the query as the title would suggest.

Answer (score 2):

Use IsNull

```
IsNull(Custom.tblR_docProducer_grdProductRating.gdlkRating, 0) AS StarID
```